# Rest API cURL POST via Google Script FetchUrlApp()

Tags: curl, post, google-apps-script, parse-platform

I’m trying to `cURL` post to Parse platform via Google Script. Tried different combinations, but always get response `400` from server. Does anyone know where the problem is in the code? Thank you all in advance!

```
function myFunction() {
  var payload = JSON.stringify({
    "score": 1337,
    "playerName": 'Sean Plott',
    "cheatMode": false
});

var headers = {
    "X-Parse-Application-Id": 'myid',
    "X-Parse-Master-Key": 'mykey',
    "X-Parse-Url": 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/',
};

var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': payload,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    //muteHttpExceptions : true,
    'headers': headers
};
var test = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://parseapi.back4app.com/classes/GameScore', options);
Logger.log(test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your options object replace `Content-Type` with `contentType`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` API correctly.

Note that 400 errors mean that

> The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
>
> [HTTP Statuses](https://httpstatuses.com/400)

In other words, your request is probably malformed. A possible cause is that you are using incorrect headers or not supplying enough information with your request.

I don't have experience with the Parse platform, but it looks like it expects a `X-Parse-REST-API-Key` header based on [this documentation](http://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/).

Comment: Try using double quotes (") in your JSON objects instead of single quotes. Does that help?

Comment: Google App Script should serialize the JavaScript objects into valid JSON before hitting the API